# How to use multiple separators in a pandas Series and split into multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas, explode

I have a dataframe like this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Name" : ["ABC LLC Ram corp", "IJK Inc"],
    "id" : [101, 102]
 })

    Name                id
0 ABC LLC Ram corp      101
1 IJK Inc               102
```

I am trying to split the Name series into multiple rows based on my separator. I am able to split but unable to retain the separators too.

`separators = ["inc","corp","llc"]`

My expected output is,

```
Name       id
ABC LLC    101
RAM corp   101
IJK Inc    102
```

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`str.findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) to find all the occurrence of matching regex pattern in column `Name`, then assign these matching occurrences to the column `Name` and `explode` the dataframe on `Name`:

```
pat = fr"(?i)(.*?(?:{'|'.join(separators)}))"
df.assign(Name=df['Name'].str.findall(pat)).explode('Name')
```

**Regex details:**

- `(?i)` : Case insensitive flag
- `(` : Start of capturing group
- `.*?` : Matches any character except line terminators between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible (`lazy match`).
- `(?:` : start of a non capturing group
- `{'|'.join(separators)}`: `f-string` expression which evaluates to `inc|corp|llc`
- `)` : End of non-capturing group
- `)` : End of capturing group

---

```
        Name   id
0    ABC LLC  101
0   Ram corp  101
1    IJK Inc  102
```

Comment: Thank you @subham , can you explain the regex if possible?

Comment: @pyd Sure give me a minute.

Comment: @pyd For now you can  check [`this link`](https://regex101.com/r/RYMw7h/1) to see the regex pattern in action. In the meantime i will edit the answer to include the details as well.

Comment: Hi @subham, how can we have variable in df.assign like `a="Name";df.assign(a,....)`

Comment: Hi @pyd I guess we can simply do `df.assign(a=<some_value>)`, where `<some_value>` could be a`scalar` or `series` or even a `list` but having same length as of the dataframe.

Comment: Hi @Subham, in some cases the word will not ends with separator, can we do anything in that case?

Comment: @pyd Lets discuss [`here`](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228691/ds5)

Answer (score 3):

A bit verbose approach , by replacing the spaces after the words with comma and then split:

```
d = dict(zip([f'{i} ' for i in separators],[f'{i},' for i in separators]))
#{'inc ': 'inc,', 'corp ': 'corp,', 'llc ': 'llc,'}

out = (df.assign(Name=df['Name'].str.lower()
       .replace(d,regex=True).str.title().str.split(",")).explode("Name"))
```

---

```
print(out)

       Name   id
0   Abc Llc  101
0  Ram Corp  101
1   Ijk Inc  102
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) @Anky, but Subham Answer does not change to title case, so that matches my expected output, not sure interms of performance